# Bootstrap datepicker inside modal scrolling with parent page, not with modal

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, css, bootstrap-modal, bootstrap-datepicker

I have got a bootstrap template wherein I gotta use datepicker inside a modal. The content of modal is scrollable. When I click on datepicker field and scroll the page, the datepicker scrolls with the parent page reference while modal content are not at all scrolled. Also, when modal is scrolled, datepicker stays on "fixed" position (as parent page is not scrolled). Any idea on how to make modal popup as a parent reference for the datepicker in bootstrap?

Answer (score 1):

The problem starts because bootstrap automatically append the widget in the "body" (default container), that is why if you work with modals you must specify the container. If You're using a bootstrap modal then You can use the "container: '.modal-body'".

$('#myInput').datepicker({
    container: '.modal-body'
});

I hope that helps!

Comment: Thank you! I messed around trying all sorts of Heath Robinson solutions - none of which worked - before finding this. I'm using the Bootstrap datepicker as a wrapped component in a Vue project and this fix works great.

Answer (score 0):

Use the datepicker('place') option:

```
$( "#model" ).scroll(function() {
    $('.datepicker').datepicker('place');
});
```

Comment: What does that parameter 'place' mean?